# How do I point to a Context Menu's parent in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've searched quite a bit but most of the solutions I found were from people asking on how to do it in C#. I wanted both to practice my XAML and reduce my already messy C# code so I decided to try it on XAML.

**What I've Tried:**

I've created a template for the Context Menu and here's my code:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Some Content -->
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Parent.IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**My understanding of the code:**

I imagined the hierarchy to be like this:

```
Parent UIControl (Can be a button, textbox, etc)
|---> Context Menu
      |---> Template
```

So with my code `Binding Parent.IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`, I expected it to work like this:

1. I've set my source to the `TemplatedParent` first (which I expected to be the `Context Menu`)
2. Now I'm trying to bind to the `Parent` (which is a UIControl of whoever uses the `Context Menu`) of my source (which at the moment I expect to be the `TemplatedParent`)

**Here's the full code of everything involved with this:**

1. Parent:

   `<Button Content="Button" ContextMenu="{DynamicResource ErrorPopup}"/>`
2. Context Menu w/ Control Template (They're stored on a ResourceDictionary since they'll be reused by other controls to display each of their own Errors):

-

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ErrorPopup" x:Shared="False">
    <ContextMenu.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                        <Grid>
                            <!-- Some Content -->
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Parent.IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.Style>
</ContextMenu>
```

**What I expect:**

I expected the Context Menu to popup when I place my cursor on top of the Button.

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to make some progress, I tried changing my binding to:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button,Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Unfortunately it's displaying some weird behavior wherein the MouseOver would show the context menu ONLY if I forcibly open a Context Menu beforehand by using my mouse's right click.

This doesn't work:

1. I hover over the Button
2. Context Menu doesn't show up

This works:

1. I right click the Button
2. Context Menu shows up
3. Closes quickly
4. Shows a Context Menu from the Mouse Over
5. I move the cursor away = Context Menu disappears
6. I move the cursor inside = Context Menu appears

Could this be because the context menu doesn't actually exist yet up until I explicitly open it through a mouse's right click? And after initializing it, only then will the triggers work?

Comment: There is no `ContextMenu` until you open it and a trigger defined a `ContextMenu` style won't ever be able to open the `ContextMenu`.

Comment: I see, thanks for confirming my suspicions, I have since moved over to a popup to satisfy my requirements.